# How do I push to a Docker registry mount on a subpath?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

If I have a registry mounted at https://x.y.z.com/registry, how must I tag my images? Docker seems to insist on prepending `v2/` to any path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [configurable](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#http) as ***prefix***.